# How to properly pass parameters to START?

Tags: windows, curl, cmd, escaping

I just want to start a curl command in a minimized console.

this works:

```
START "" /B /W curl -X POST https://someurl.com -d "url_parameters_for_curl" > output.txt
```

But this does not work

```
START "" /MIN /W curl -X POST https://someurl.com -d "url_parameters_for_curl" > output.txt
```

I think it has something to do with the double quotes. I tried multiple escaping characters like ^ or "" and triple """ which worked for some other programs but START does not seem to be able to escape the double quotes when opening a new console window...

I've spent like 2 hours now trying to figure this out and I have no idea what to do.

PS: putting the command in a .bat file and calling it with

```
START /MIN /W mybat.bat
```

is working. But the command is generated on the fly and I don't want to write a file each time.

PPS: the command is spawned by a background process without a console window which leads to a console window popping up every time this happens. I just wanted it to appear minimized.

EDIT:

The hint with escaping the

```
> output.xml
```

with

```
^> output.xml  OR ^>output.xml
```

did not work. But curl has an option to write the output to a file. So this finally worked:

```
START "" /MIN /W curl -X POST https://someurl.com -d "url_parameters_for_curl" -o output.txt
```

The question remains: How would you escape the "> outputfile" using the START command?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? please be precise! the double-quotes shouldn't be a problem, maybe you even need more of them around the URL…

Comment: I agree: the quotes shouldn't be a problem. I guess your `output.txt` is empty? You redirect the output of the `start` command - which is empty. Escape the `>` to pass it to the started process: `...^>output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I would say, because `curl.exe` is a CLI process, that it isn't cURL you need to minimize, but the `cmd.exe` window it spawns to run within.

For that reason, I'd offer:

```batch-file
Start /Min /W %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D/Q/C "%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe -X POST https://someurl.com -d "url_parameters_for_curl" 1> "output.txt" 2>&1"
```

In the example above, I've also redirected StdErr to the file, *(because you wouldn't see that, in a minimized window)*. If you don't want that, you can remove `2>&1` from above.